# Edit a Sharepoint List with Access VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, sharepoint, sharepoint-list

I have created a Sharepoint list and then imported that list into Access.
I only created UserName, FirstName, LastName, LastLogIn, and LastVersion. But there seem to be a few other columns that come in by default with Sharepoint.

I can open that linked List and add in new records in the table view mode. They show up in Sharepoint as well.
[image]
[image]

My problem is when I try editing a line with VBA, I get an error that it is read only.

```
100     Dim sql As String
110     sql = "SELECT " & _
                  "* " & _
              "FROM " & _
                  "tblUsers " & _
                  "INNER JOIN " & _
                  "tblSettings " & _
                  "ON " & _
                  "tblUsers.UserName = tblSettings.UserName "

120     Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(sql)
130     rst.MoveFirst
140     rst.Edit
150     rst.Fields("LastLogIn") = Now
160     rst.Fields("LastVersion") = version
170     rst.Update
180     rst.Close
```

FYI: this simple code is to let me know when the last time they logged in was and what version of the front end they last used.

I get the following error

> 3027: Cannot update. Database or object is read-only.

This code worked perfectly when the table was a linked table from another Access file. But now that I'm trying to move the backend into a Sharepoint list, VBA seems to only be able to read only.
Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried removing the join and keep the updating table only?

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out the answer was to use a SQL statement to update the table.

Here is my code.

```
100     Dim sql As New sqlClass
110     With sql
120         .Add "UPDATE"
130         .Add "    tblSettings"
140         .Add "    INNER JOIN"
150         .Add "    tblUsers"
160         .Add "    ON"
170         .Add "    tblSettings.UserName = tblUsers.UserName"
180         .Add "SET"
190         .Add "    tblUsers.LastLogin = #" & Now & "#,"
200         .Add "    tblUsers.LastVersion = """ & version & """"
210         .Execute
220     End With
```

Obviously, I have a custom class in there, but basically, the SqlClass holds the statement and has a function inside it that runs this:

```
CurrentDb.Execute Me.Code, dbFailOnError
```

`Me.Code` is the string containing the SQL statement code in the SqlClass.

Hope this helps someone else.